# C struct copy in C++ constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor

My problem is with the following code:

```
extern "C" struct CStruct {
  char a;
  char b;
};

class X {
  CStruct cs;

public:
  X(CStruct cs_arg) : cs{cs_arg} {}
  X(CStruct cs, bool){
    this->cs = cs;
  }

};
```

Clang 3.4 (c++11) complains for the first constructor but not for the second one.

```
../st2.cpp:10:25: error: no viable conversion from 'CStruct' to 'char'
        X(CStruct cs_arg) : cs{cs_arg} {}
                               ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

How come it says conversion to char if the `cs` member is clearly a struct?
Can i make this kind of initalization work in the initialization list or must i do it in the function body? Why?

The real code uses a template for the class and it fails if the type is a simple POD struct. It should never handle anything more complex then POD structs.

Comment: Your error  isn't consistent with your code (wrong constructor).. nvm, just got edited :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to initialize cs? Then the code may be corrected like

```
  X(CStruct cs_arg) : cs(cs_arg) {}             // change cs_arg{cs} to cs(cs_arg)
```

Here the copy constructor will be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You are using aggregate initialization.

You should have

```
cs {char1, char2} .
```

If you want initialiation from another struct, you should use

```
cs(cs_arg).
```

Or, if you don't want to make a copy constructor use

```
cs{cs_arg.a, cs_arg.b};
```

Comment: What if now instead i have `template<class T>class X{ T cs}` how would i initialize that?

Comment: Try implementing a copy constructor and see if that works. Aggregate initialization is a list initialiaztion. Also try posting the exact code (or a template example at least if code isn't possible) since you might get answers for your specifically asked question (such as I did)